# Audio distorted when playing flash

Tags: flash, audio, browser

When I open a video/audio track with my browser (Firefox or Chrome), the sound is very distorted. However this doesn't happen when opening a media file or something that runs with Java, so I believe is a Flash problem.

I've tried uninstalling flash and re-installing Chrome and Firefox, but the problem persists. The flash version I'm currently using is 11,3,300,257. I'm using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
Apparently it's a bug in the 11.3 version of flash. Following [this post](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1026022) I uninstalled the 11.3 version and installed an old 10.3 one and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that at least for Fedora Systems it is sufficient to just restart the pulseaudio deamon. So whenever my chrome jitters I do the following:

```
pulseadio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

Then reload the page and you're good to till the next chrash.